# Python ThreadPoolExecutor: future.result randomly returns None

Tags: python, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

So I have the following code for threading:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                    futures = []
                    for url in total_links:
                        futures.append(executor.submit(process_url, input_url=url))
                    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                        print('RESULT INSIDE')
                        result = future.result() #Returns None randomly
                        print(result)
                        records.append(result)
```

At times `future.result()` returns None. Below is the `process_url` function:

```
def process_url(input_url):
    res = None
    sleep(0.07)
    r = session.get(input_url, headers=headers, cookies=c, cert=cert, timeout=20)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        res = get_status(soup)
        print('Inside Process URL')
        print(res)
        print('======================')
    return res
```

`res` will always have data available but that data is not being fetched under thread. I also add that it is happening randomly that is, If I run script 5 times then at least once it returns `None`.

Comment: can you please wrap the `process_url` method inside a `try`...`exception` block and see if there is any exception being thrown and print the same ? the `process_url` may be returning `None` in such cases.

Comment: @vshenoy sorry for late response. No, no exception thrown. Neither without exception it shows anything

Comment: Add an `else` clause to `process_url` with a print inside it, and I bet you'll see it printed, meaning some of the URLs returned a non-200 status. Either that, or `get_status`, which you didn't show, can return None.

Comment: @user4815162342 no print function always returned the correct values.

Comment: Did you add it in the `else` clause as  well? Did you add a `print` at the end of `get_status` (which you still didn't show in the question)?

Answer (score 0):

So there may be several issues, but most notably if you don't receive a status code of 200 the futures object will return None. For example, say a thread goes and retrieves a URL, but a following thread is unable to reach a host, the request gets timed out, etc. that thread will report back None.

You could validate this behavior by:

1. Making sure each request is actually working, e.g making sure res=None changes to to the success state in your thread. What happens if the request times out? Are you returning those details? If not, res=None
2. Adding logic to show errors, e.g. make sure res=None is referencing a response.

   ```
   def process_url(input_url):
    res = None
    sleep(0.07)
    r = session.get(input_url, headers=headers, cookies=c, cert=cert, timeout=20)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        res = get_status(soup)
        print('Inside Process URL')
        print(res)
        print('======================')
    if r.status_code != 200:
        res = r.text
    return res
   ```

I would potentially use a dictionary instead of an array as the futures object so you can reference each thread by it's url. Right now, its by index. This way you can know which url is the culprit.

```
# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 20): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
            return "Something went wrong!"
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
            return "Success!"
```

But the process you're running is not "randomly" returning None. The res object is referencing None during your execution. The only time you may also receive a None object is if the thread isn't collecting a result. Here are the docs for reference.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result